# What are these errors happening at the time of boot macbook pro?

Tags: catalina, startup

I have macbook pro 2013 , recently updated to Catalina.

I have started seeing these error shown in images below ?

[image]
This error happens often.

The one shown below happens captured in video rarely.
Blinking folder with question mark in it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFdx6nY3s6k

In 2018 I myself swapped HDD to SSD but recently it started showing the above two errors.

hangs a lot. gets heated and I had to frequently force reboot

Comment: Make a Backup ASAP if you dont have one already. Blinking folder with question mark in it means there is no OS to boot from, i.e. no boot drive could be detected. With this little knowledge and without having seen and used the machine its hard to give any good hints, but my gut tells me that there is something wrong with the connection to the SSD.

Comment: possible because I connected ssd myself when I migrated hdd to ssd years back and few weeks back my macbook fell down.